# Obtaining an int value of an object from an arrayList containing objects in jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp, session, arraylist, foreach

I was having a problem with obtaining an id value from an object in a list. I am first storing user login details in a session and using these to set the criteria for a query that i use to populate the list. The list will only hold one object of type user.
The list is being populated with the correct details as I checked through debugging, however when I try to iterate the list to obtain the id value of the object stored in the list my code does not even enter the for loop. The id value is the id of the user that the query is obtaining.
The following is my code snippet:

```
        HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();

        LoggedUser lu = (LoggedUser) session1.getAttribute("logged");

         String uname = lu.getUserName();
         String pword = lu.getPass();


         List<Users> ulist = session.createSQLQuery("Select * From Users WHERE Username = '" + uname + "'" + " AND Password = " + "'" + pword+ "'").list();

         int uid = 0; // up until here everything works fine with debugging

         for(Users user : ulist)
         {
             uid = user.getId();
         }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please do not implement your login  with concatenated string queries. It is a big security hole. See SQL injection. You should rather use named query parameters.

Comment: You are right, however for the task I have at hand i was asked to carry it out in that way for simplicity. Once a user logs in his username and password are stored and in the above code I then call these details in order to add the user publication and the user id of the current logged user to the database in order to later display RSS feeds for the current logged user.
Is there no way how I can obtain the id value from the above code?

Comment: Except for the Hibernate part, it looks right to me. If the loop is never entered, the list must be empty. You can know by printing the list size for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start using hibernate criteria like this,

```
List<Users> ulist = (List<Users>) session.createCriteria(Users.class)
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("username", uname))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("password", pword)).list();
```

Also what is the datatype for id in your Users class? If it is int,

```
if(null != ulist && ulist.size() > 0){
     int uid = 0; 

     for(Users user : ulist)
     {
         uid = user.getId();
     }
}
```

**Updated**

Everywhere you need to check null. Else you may come across lot of nullpointer exceptions.

```
LoggedUser lu = (LoggedUser) session1.getAttribute("logged");
String uname = "";
String pword = "";
if(null != session1.getAttribute("logged")){
    uname = lu.getUserName();
    pword = lu.getPass();
}
```

Hope this helps.